# What does the "plot interval" scroll bar do in the MATLAB Neural Network Toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network

What does the "Plot Interval" bar (in the image below) change when moved to say a 100 epochs? I noticed that the training time is decreased significantly the larger the interval is but I do not understand if this affects the learning of my neural network. For example, I noticed that when the interval is set to 1 epoch the training time is slow and it gives a low mse error. When set to a 100 epochs, the training time is significantly faster but the mse error is still low.

What is happening here?

[image: ANN GUI]

Comment: shows how your training state, performance and other parameters changing with defined epoch step

Comment: so it doesn't affect performance?

Comment: It should not affect performance. What it does is that updating all three plots after each epoch. Increasing interval you spend less time on updating results. If there is no need to track network performance with time I would suggest to increase plot interval as